# Same functionality, new contract for new usage?

Tags: transactions, contract-design, contract-invocation

When different people use the same contract functionality, do they send to the same contract address? Or do they create their own new copies of the contract at a different address? If they use the same address, how does the network distinguish the different parallel usages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It depends on what the contract does.**

If a contract is library-like and reusable, all senders could use the same contract: a trivial example is a contract that converts temperature (between Celsius and Fahrenheit).  In this example, there's no issue about parallel usage because there is no shared state: everyone will get the answer they expect.  When shared state is involved, the transactions are processed in an order determined by the miner, for an illustration see: [What happens when a smart contract gets several similar calls in the same block?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2856/42)

But for a contract like a [wallet](https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/blob/master/wallet/wallet.sol), everyone would want to create and send to their own [instance of the contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1102/42).