# How to Deploy and call a contract? Address needed beforehand?

Tags: web3js, transactions, contract-deployment, contract-invocation, addresses

I want to store a string from a script in node.js to blockchain.
This is the contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
    string storedData;

    function set(string x) {
        storedData = x;
    }

    function get() constant returns (string) {
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

In order to deploy the contract on net(in my case testnet) I need to create an instance of the contract. In order to create an instance and deploy it I need 3 things: web3 library, abi and address of contract:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
abi = JSON.parse(....)  //==> I got abi following this tutorial(https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-1-40d2d0d807c2)
StoreContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
contractInstance = VotingContract.at('CONTRACT ADDRESS');
//And now I can use contract function
contractInstance.set(string data)
```

So my question is....How do I get the contract address???

Comment: In the posted code here `contractInstance = VotingContract.at('CONTRACT ADDRESS');` it should be `StoreContract` not `VotingContract`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need address and ABI to invoke a contract. Before invoking a contract you need to deploy it. You have only got the abi definition. You need to deploy the contract by letting it be mined and get the address. Use,

```
var simpleStorage = StoreContract.new(your_parameters ,{from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data: compiled_code , gas: gas_amount}, call_back_function)
```

Once the contract is mined, it will return something like this,

```
Contract mined! address: contract_address
```

where you can find the contract address at *contract_address*

Refer the basic [greeter example](https://www.ethereum.org/greeter) provided in the Ethereum web site for a detailed explanation on beginning with smart contracts.

**UPDATE-1:**

If you carefully read the [blog post](https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-1-40d2d0d807c2) you referred, it's clearly given that you need to send a transaction for the contract to be deployed.(it has some nice diagrams too)

This is the code snippet from the blog post,

> ```
> abiDefinition = JSON.parse(compiledCode.contracts[':Voting'].interface)
> VotingContract = web3.eth.contract(abiDefinition)
> byteCode = compiledCode.contracts[':Voting'].bytecode
>   // the following line is what you need to do get the address
> deployedContract = VotingContract.new(['Rama','Nick','Jose'],{data: byteCode, from:
> web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 4700000}) 
> deployedContract.address
> contractInstance = VotingContract.at(deployedContract.address)
> ```

and from what you posted,

> ```
> var Web3 = require('web3');
> var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
> abi = JSON.parse(....)  //==> I got abi following this tutorial(https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-1-40d2d0d807c2)
> //at this point you need to send the transaction using "StoredContract.new(params,transaction details, callback[optional]);"  
> StoreContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
> contractInstance = VotingContract.at('CONTRACT ADDRESS');
> ```

You don't need a address to deploy a contract, you just need to send a transaction with the contract details. Once the contract is deployed(after the transaction is mined) it will output the address which you can use to call the particular instance.

**UPDATE-2:**

You may deploy many instance of the same contract by sending transactions and they are stored at different addresses. You can use a particular instance using the respective address (eg: to call a function like setter in your case). Refer the following answer posted [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1102/18241).

> Just like code can be in source form, or converted/compiled to
>   executable form, the same thing applies to contracts.
>
> From source code, many copies of the executable form can be generated.
>
> In source code form, a contract in Solidity is like a class in OOP
>   terms: it can be instantiated many times, and can be inherited from.
>
> Making a contract executable, usually involves 2 steps:
>
> converting the source to Ethereum Virtual Machine (EVM) bytecode
>   deploying the EVM to an Ethereum blockchain The same contract source
>   code or EVM can be deployed to a blockchain many times. Each instance
>   of a deployed contract has a unique address.

Comment: Ok,I'll try,thanks.Just last question: is the contract ok?I red somewhere it could be problem with string parameter

Comment: No wait..I have a doubt..I need contract address to deploy my contract,but in order to have contract address first I have to deploy my contract??I am a little bit confused

Comment: I am using TestRPC fwi

Comment: I think it's clearly mentioned in the blog post you referred [here](https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-1-40d2d0d807c2) . let me update the answer relating the blog post.

Comment: So...(just to be sure I've understood you)once deployed,I can use that address to create new istance of my contract?

Comment: an instance of a contracts is deployed at a particular address. You can initiate many instances at different addresses. What you do with the address is calling that particular instance

Comment: I updated the answer again

Comment: Ok so I can't do what I thought... I need to pass some data ,contained in a string,in a js script to the contract.So I need to call an istance of the contract in my script and use the function set,like this contractInstance.set(string data)                                   I thought I could use that address for a new istance of my contract,but as you said the address is referred to that particular istance ...So how could I do that??(sorry for the double question..)

Comment: till now i wrote all lines from cmd. Could I use this var simpleStorage = StoreContract.new(your_parameters ,{from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data: compiled_code , gas: gas_amount}, call_back_function)  in the js script ? Using my string "data" as "your_parameters)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65604/discussion-between-achala-dissanayake-and-nick9214).

Comment: How'd this code work, if we used "truffle compile" or "truffle deploy". I can get things to work for new instances. But, if I try to load from an address, nothing works.

Comment: how to get the abi of a public deployed contract for whose address i only now from etherescan ?